# Can't locate node [joints_receive_from_arduino.py] in package [ros_control_example]

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to build and run ros_control_example(https://github.com/bandasaikrishna/ros_control_example) package.
But, it seems I have done something wrong.

I have created catkin_ws folder and cloned it from github to catkin_ws/src folder and catkin_make finished without any error. And also I have added it to .bashrc(source catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash)

But when I try to run this package with "roslaunch ros_control_example check_velocity_controller.launch"

it gives "ERROR: cannot launch node of type [ros_control_example/joints_receive_from_arduino.py]: can't locate node [joints_receive_from_arduino.py] in package [ros_control_example]" But that python code "joints_receive_from_arduino.py" is under "~/catkin_ws/src/ros_control_example/ros_control_example/scripts/" folder.

And an empty rviz starts.

What should I have to do to solve this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400540/can%27t-locate-node-%5Bjoints_receive_from_arduino.py%5D-in-package-%5Bros_control_example%5D/) by [mustafaxfe](https://answers.ros.org/users/34793/mustafaxfe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-05-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-12**:
I've updated the title of your post to better reflect what the problem is you report.

This is not related to RViz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you make your file readable? I mean the python file .

Chmod +× (name of .py file )

In the package you cloned you will have a .py file in the launch file

You have to make the .py file executable from the src folder . Cd into the src and  make the file readable

---

Originally posted by [Davies Ogunsina](https://answers.ros.org/users/103873/davies-ogunsina/) with karma: 96 on 2022-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0